# How can I catch the error and output an empty list instead? Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following problem:
I have built a filter with Spring Boot that searches for the locations by its externalId or name. If I enter parts of the name as filterCriteria then I get the right results. But if I enter something wrong as filterCriteria then I get back the below listed "404 Not found". I would rather get back an empty list because of the error.
How can I catch the error and output an empty list instead?

My Controller

```java
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<SolarPanelLocation>> getSolarPanelLocationsByIdAndName(String solarPanelNameAndExternalId) {
    return ResponseEntityBuilderUtils.ok(solarPanelService.getSolarPanelFilterByExternalIdAndSolarPanelName(solarPanelNameAndExternalId));
}
```

My Service

```java
@Override
public List<SolarPanelLocation> getSolarPanelFilterByExternalIdAndSolarPanelName(String solarPanelNameAndExternalId) {

        if (solarPanelNameAndExternalId == null) {
            throw new MissingValueException("The externalId or solarPanelName are required");
        }
        final List<SolarPanelLocationEntityView> solarPanelLocationEntityListFilter = solarPanelLocationDAO.filterSolarPanelList(
                solarPanelNameAndExternalId);
        if (solarPanelLocationEntityListFilter == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementFoundException("Structure Group Location list not available");
        }
        if (solarPanelLocationEntityListFilter.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementFoundException("Solar Panel Location list not available");
        }
        return solarPanelLocationMapper.map(solarPanelLocationEntityListFilter);
    }
```

My DAO with Query

```java
@Query("SELECT d FROM SolarPanelLocationEntityView d WHERE d.externalId LIKE %:#{#filterCriteria}% OR lower(d.solarPanelName) LIKE lower(concat('%',:filterCriteria,'%')) ")
List<SolarPanelLocationEntityView> filterSolarPanelList(@Param("filterCriteria") String filterCriteria);
```

My Postman result

```json
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "Solar Panel Location list not availablen"
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```java
if (solarPanelLocationEntityListFilter.isEmpty()) {
    return List.of();
}
```

Comment: Why not let the service return an empty list?

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer, accept it so that the question can be "closed" and others benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just had to play in the service not the error code, but an empty list.

```
if (solarPanelLocationEntityListFilter.isEmpty()) {
    return List.of();
}
```